# Route All Requests to Subfolder htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm building an application for broad distribution and I want to change the way it's routed so that all the files can exist in the document root but still be secure as if they were above the doc root.

The ideal set up would be to house the application folder above the docroot like so:

```
/home
/---/username
/---/--->application
/---/---/--->all application files
/---/--->public_html
/---/---/--->all public files
```

But I know this isn't ideal for all potential users of my app, so I'd prefer to move this to a structure like so:

```
/home
/---/username
/---/--->public_html
/---/---/--->application
/---/---/---/--->all application files
/---/---/--->public
/---/---/---/-->all public files
```

Basically just putting everything within the doc root, forbidding access to the application directory, and routing all requests to the public folder, so that we can get the same security of having files above the doc root, but making it simpler for those that may not want this type of set up for their shared hosts.

I was thinking of using an include inside `public_html/index.php` that would include `public_html/public/index.php` but I can't seem to get that to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it you want to have `home/username/public_html` as the **real** Apache Document Root, deny access from the `/application` directory and, ideally, route all web requests into the `/public` sub-directory instead (presumably for users not on dedicated servers who can't install outside of the docroot) *... If I've misunderstood the question let me know and I'll update/remove the answer ;)*

You should be able to achieve this with an .htaccess file in `/home/username/public_html` like:

```
RewriteEngine on

# deny access to the application directory
RewriteRule ^application/?  - [F]

# route all requests to the public directory that aren't already there
RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*)$   /public/$1  [L,QSA]
```

Any attempts to access the `/application` directory will result in a 403 error and all requests to `http://www.myserver.tld/file.ext` will be routed to `http://www.myserver.tld/public/file.ext`.

**Caveat:** To prevent recursive loops of the redirect, the rewrite rule will **not** redirect any URL path that already begins with `/public` ... this means that any file under `/public` will be accessible on both the `http://www.mysite.tld/filename.ext` **and** `http://www.mysite.tld/public/filename.ext` - which *may* upset search engines.

---

To be extra safe you could also add an `.htaccess` file to the `/application` directory like:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect, thanks a bunch.  Is it possible to stop direct calling of the public folder, or rather re-writing it so that it doesn't show up in the address?

Comment: I think it would have to be done client side (JavaScript); read the browser's address bar and `document.location` redirect from there if needed... the server only knows about what the request actually is and what we're doing is routing the request to the public folder. Attempting to route requests from `/public/` back up to `/` and then routing them back to `/public/` to fetch the actual file just ends up with horrible, horrible recursive loops... I did try a few things server-side without much luck :|

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public_html/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public_html/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Don't think that'll work as I'm guessing `public_html` is the actual Apache Document Root.

Comment: Oh, I thought he wanted everything directed there so it can't be accessed by the document root. @CD001

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any framework in your app?

Have you a sample of code we could access to understand your problem?

Basically, you just need an htaccess in your public_html folder that redirect the request to the public folder and disable the access to any other directory than public.